# How to search a binary tree node for a string?

Tags: java, binary-tree, binary-search-tree

How do I look for what is contained in a node?  What I mean by that is how do I make the comparison?  What do I do different to make that work?  I know, or at least I think I know, that I have to pass the search method the String and the Node.

```
if (value == root)
        return root;
```

Comment: can you include the implementation of your tree?

very little context to give you an answer.

Comment: *"...how do I make the comparison?"* For a `String` type, use `equals()`

Answer (score 1):

In your tag you say it is a binary tree (altough this does not mean it is a sorted tree).

What you can do in the case of a sorted tree:

```
public String searchTree (Node n, String searchVal)
{
   if (n.isEmpty())//no more children
   {
      return null;
   }
   else if (n.root().toString().equals(searchVal) //we found it
   {
      return n.root();
   }
   else if (searchVal < n.root().toString()) //search left child
   {
      return searchTree(n.leftChild(),searchVal);
   }
   else //search right child
   {
      return searchTree(n.rightChild(),searchVal);
   }
}
```

This is the basic code but needs to be refined for you Tree class
In case the tree is not sorted, the last if-statements can be combined (first check left tree; if that is null return the search on the right tree, otherwise return the search on the left tree)

Kind regards,
Héctor van den Boorn

Comment: The tree is not sorted. It is just balanced. I am just doing if left is null add, else if right is null add, else if node count left is less than or equal to right, add left, else add right.  I should have thought of the toString method.  It looks like that will take care of it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

treeSet.contains(object)

Where treeSet is an instance of TreeSet and object is an instance of something that overrides equals() and hashcode() properly.